# Grouping results with SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have an array of objects that I'm able to render in a SwiftUI view. It's very simple to display them as a List, however I'd like to create sections and group by one of the elements' properties.

I tried up using `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` and then sorting by the dictionary's keys to get the sections, however this slows the UI down. It feels like I'm doing something wrong.

```swift
            List {
                ForEach(myArray.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { mySection in
                    Section(header: Text(mySection)) {
                        ForEach(myArray[mySection] ?? []) { element in
                            NavigationLink {
                                DetailView(element: element)
                            } label: {
                                ElementRow(element: element)
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Is there a more efficient way than `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` to group data retrieved from SwiftData into sections?

Comment: Good job on finding a solution. I was going to try answering, but ran into the problem of not seeing your use of Dictionary(grouping:by:) in your code. If that is where your slowdown is coming from, we can't comment on it, unless we can see it. But if you're happy with your solution, then all's good! BTW, the code that you've shared doesn't not have any gross inefficiencies that I can see. There are some, but not enough to cause slowdowns.

Answer (score 1):

I found a framework on GitHub called [SectionedQuery](https://github.com/Whiffer/swiftdata-sectionedquery) which does exactly what I need it to:

```swift
    @State private var searchTerm = ""

    @SectionedQuery(sectionIdentifier: \MyObject.id ,
                        sortDescriptors: [
        SortDescriptor(\MyObject.property1),
        SortDescriptor(\ MyObject.property2)
    ],
           animation: .smooth
    )
    var sections

    // stuff

    List {
        // my list consuming sections
    }
    .searchable(text: $searchTerm)
```

To use it with a predicate, I did the following:

```swift
List {
    // list code
}
.searchable(text: $searchTerm)
.onChange(of: searchTerm) {
    togglePredicate()
}

func togglePredicate() {
    guard !searchTerm.isEmpty else {
        sections.predicate = nil
        return
    }

    sections.predicate = #Predicate<MyThing> {
        $0.someProperty.localizedStandardContains(searchTerm)
    }
}
```

Comment: Watch out for the `while true` (line 75 SectionedQuery.swift) in that framework! And they shouldn't be using `Task { }` in SwiftUI it is `.task`.

Comment: @malhal I'll take a peek at it later. You should open a PR up into it :)

Comment: Good idea but thought I'd start by asking a question in an issue! https://github.com/Whiffer/swiftdata-sectionedquery/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List` try [`OutlineGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup) for your grouped data.

You might need to transform your data into groups which you can do in a computed property in the parent `View`'s body where you init the `View` that contains the `OutlineGroup`.